# how to call date function of table columns in JPQL

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, jpql, openjpa

Does any one know what is the JPQL counterpart  in openJPA  for the following SQL
`Select * from emptable where  date(TALBLE_COL_YYYY ||'-'||TALBLE_COL_MM||'-'`
  `||TALBLE_COL_DD) < current_date`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have 3 separate columns to represent a date instead just a single DATE column?

Comment: I think year, month and day are spread across different columns in database, that is why user2362609 is trying to concat them

Comment: yes, you are right Koitoer